# Match all children width to widest child width in ConstraintLayout with width = wrap content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

ConstraintLayout is powerful but tricky sometimes.

I want to implement a layout with the `ConstraintLayout` which can be easily achieved with the `LinearLayout`.

- The Blue area is parent constraintLayout. The red part is LinearLayout. I want to convert this LinearLayout to ConstraintLayout by maintaining the following conditions

  1. All children (Buttons)'s width should match the widest child.
  2. The widest child is not fixed. It will be changed at runtime.
  3. The red box should remain to maintain `wrap_content`.

     [image]
     [image]

I have tried with doing with barrier, guidelines and other properties of constraint layout without success.

Here is the code with `LinearLayout`:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#476dce"
android:padding="16dp">

  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:background="#f5aaaa">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:text="Small" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:text="Bigggggeer" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:text="Even Bigggggggggeer" />

  </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Why do you want replace linear layout?

Comment: Yes. I want to place ConstraintLayout instead of LinearLayout.

Comment: You can do if you know which child width is maximum.. Set that child width to `wrap_content` & set remaining child width to match contraints.

Comment: This is the definitive answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59061950/646002

Answer (score 3):

The current 1.1 stable release allows a tricky solution based on Barriers and separate backgrounds.

[image]

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#f5aaaa"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button3_txt"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_barrier"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/right_barrier"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button1_txt" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button1_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="small"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2_txt"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button2_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Bigggggeer"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3_txt"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button1_txt" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button3_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:text="Even Bigggggggggeer"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2_txt" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button1_txt"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_barrier"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/right_barrier"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button1_txt" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button2_txt"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_barrier"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/right_barrier"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button2_txt" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button3_txt"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_barrier"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/right_barrier"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button3_txt" />

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/right_barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="end"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="button1_txt, button2_txt, button3_txt" />

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/left_barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="start"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="button1_txt, button2_txt, button3_txt" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

We can separate texts from buttons, and set two barriers at each end to track the biggest text between the three TextViews. 
 So now, Buttons act only as a background and as click zones, and, they are set to match constraint between the two barriers.

You might want to be careful with elevation related to texts as Buttons have elevation by default.
Of course, if you are not into Buttons' animated elevation, change them to views.

 Finally, ConstraintLayout has the chains feature to mimic LinearLayout's behavior in a more flexible way.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please refrain from downvoting a working solution. This won't help other developers.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. Why  did you separate the text from the buttons?  And could you further explain how the barriers and the chains work?  I am also confused by this new and powerful layout.

Comment: @ScottBiggs buttons visually are equal to text with a background. I had to separate to get the needed behavior. Even though it works, it's not the ideal solution. Here is an article i wrote that explains ConstraintLayout in detail. (https://android.jlelse.eu/constraintlayout-in-the-limelight-6c22b54d9726) Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

Here is the modified layout using `ConstraintLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#476dce"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f5aaaa"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            tools:text="Small" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button1"
            tools:text="Bigggggeer" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button2"
            tools:text="Even Bigggggggggeer" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: downvoters, may I know the reason of down vote ?. It will help me to improve accordingly

Comment: Changing LinearLayout to ConstraintLayout doesn't make it ConstraintLayout's way. It's still nested and it goes against what the library what created for. Plus, match parent won't work. CL supports match constraint (0dp).