# Adjust width of multiple buttons to follow the button with the largest wrap content width in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

How do I make it so that multiple buttons follow the width of the button with the largest `wrap_content` width using Constraint Layout?

What I want are illustrated below:

[image: First Image]

All the buttons follow the last button's `wrap_content` width as it is the longest.

[image: Second Image]

All the buttons follow the first button's `wrap_content` width now.

This question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51901950/match-all-children-width-to-widest-child-width-in-constraintlayout-with-width), but the [solution that was provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51907256/9060223) is very hackish. I want the buttons to remain to be a single `Button` (unlike the proposed solution which uses a `TextView` and an empty `Button` to form one `Button` for display). Is there a better way to do the above without using a hackish solution?

Comment: This question has been asked many times on Stack Overflow and I have not seen a satisfactory answer that uses a direct native feature of _ConstraintLayout_. The best solutions that I have seen are like the one you reference where the same-size views are somehow ghosted by other views that give the right measurements for the size needed. There is a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59061950/6287910) that uses a _ConstraintHelper_ that may work for you - still a little "hackish" but easy to understand. I would like to see a better native solution if one exists.

Comment: This is the definitive answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59061950/646002